# c# rtb: Bolden inline overrides another bolden inline

Tags: c#, regex, windows-10-universal

My projekt is a Windows 10 universal app!

I almost have for two month the problem, that when I bold two words in one rtb, the second overrides the first bold inline.

Example:

I want to bold:

```
Hello; Bye
```

Text from rtb:

```
Hello and Bye
```

Now I search with regex, weather ther is "Hello"/ "Bye" in rtb.
For each time there is "Hello" in rtb I insert a bolden inline with the text "Hello" in the same Position than "hello" stand befor.

After that I make the same with "Bye".

My Code:

```
string text = run.Text; -> "Hello and Bye"

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, "Hello", RegexOptions.Multiline);

int i = 0;
var bold = new Bold();
int iIn = 0;
int iLe = 0;
p.Inlines.Clear(); -> p = Paragraph from rtb

foreach (Match match in mc)
{
       p.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(i, match.Index - i) });
       bold.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(match.Index, match.Length) });
       p.Inlines.Add(bold);
       i = match.Index + match.Length;

       if (i < text.Length)
       {
             p.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = text.Substring(i) });
       }
}
```

This is followed by the same Code with bye.

Now the Problem is, that I clear the first bold inline (**Hello**) while insert the second bold inline (**Bye**).

Does anyone know an alternative to bold an specific word in a rtb or a Suggestion to improve the Code? I almost tryed everything but nothing really worked...

Comment: Are you calling `p.Inlines.Clear()` once or twice?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I call it bevore adding the bolden inline from hello and from bye.

Comment: @ehh This sounds nice, but I cant convert an int to an Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.TextPointer (comment to answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in order to select the relevant characters to make bold:"

```
public void Select(
  TextPointer start, 
  TextPointer end
)

In order to get TextPointer, try this (not checked):

TextPointer pointer = document.ContentStart;

TextPointer start = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(0);
TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(5);

rtb.Select (start,end); // for example to select Hello
                 // Then change the font to bold
```

Comment: In my Project visual Studio says, that rtb.selectionstart only gets the value?? How do I make it?

Comment: Looks, I added a picture that shows SelectionStart has getter and setter.

Comment: @Dieter Müller, from which assembly your rich textbox belongs?

Comment: Sry for the question, but where do I find the assembly of rtb out? (I uploaded Picture of SelectionStart only have getter :( at the bottom of question)

Comment: If you press F12 on the variable richTextBox (in my case) you will go to its definition, you should see:
private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox;

Comment: This sounds nice, but I cant convert an int to an Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.TextPointer

Comment: I know its not fun, but there is no CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset

Comment: Yes, it finally work!!! But everything (like "Bold boldx = new Bold(Start, end);" dont work). It would be so nice, if you could help me once again! :) I know I'm a really nooby beginer, but that would help me so much :D.

Comment: Use new Font("Arial",12,Bold)

Comment: any other suggestions, cause there is no "new Font" in Windows 10 app :(

Comment: do you have really no idea? :(

Comment: Need to make some Google on it

Comment: Try to set FontStyle